Autofs fails to mount a Windows share
I've got two machines: a 10.0.0.1 Windows 10 which shares one folder /Users/WS/Shared/, and a 10.0.0.2 CentOS 7 from which I want to mount this share. I can do this from commandline using:
mount -t cifs -o username=<user>,password=<pass> //10.0.0.1/Users/WS/Shared /home/admin/Shared

and everything works, listing /home/admin/Shared shows the expected stuff inside.
Now I want to have this mounted with autofs. So, following some guides, here's what I did:

/etc/auto.master:

/home/admin/Shared /etc/auto.10.0.0.1


/etc/auto.10.0.0.1:

Shared -fstype=cifs,rw,user=<user>,pass=<pass> ://10.0.0.1/Users/WS/Shared

Then a restart of the autofs deamon (systemctl restart autofs) and... it doesn't work: listing /home/admin/Shared shows an empty directory. No logs anywhere. Then in another guide (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) I read that in order to see some logs, I have to stop the deamon and start it manually with the '-v' switch like so:
systemctl stop autofs
automount -f -v

When I do the above, autofs prints some initial messages (I am not at the station right now, so I cannot paste them, but they did not look like errors to me) and then, when - on a different console - I do a 'ls /home/admin/Shared' it prints... absolutely nothing. So it doesn't look like it is even trying to do anything?
How to debug this further?

have you tried -o remount it will cycle usually the mount point

what you are seeing is actually the expected behaviour. You won't see anything unless you go to the directory or list its contents.
Listing /home/admin/Shared shows an empty directory because you are in the wrong directory. In /etc/auto.master you set the mount point to /home/admin/Shared and in /etc/auto.10.0.0.1 you set another mount point inside the first mount point. The resulting mount point is /home/admin/Shared/Shared. If everything else is correct you will have access to your files under this directory.
